# Bash: Clearing the screen completely including prompt

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash code that read input from a file.

```
for line in $(cat python.py); do
read input
echo $input;
echo "[$line]"
done
```

What i want is to read input  in a complete  clear terminal screen including the prompt like it does in VIM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can clear the prompt by changing the environment variable PS1.
Something like

```
OLDPS1=$PS1
PS1=
clear
```

should clear your screen and let you input whatever you want with no prompt at all. Restore the variable PS1 once finished with

```
PS1=$OLDPS1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export PS1="";printf "\033[2J";printf "\033[0;0H"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
while read line; do
   read input
   echo $input;
   echo "[$line]"
   clear
done < python.py
```

See `clear` at the end of the loop to clear the terminal.

Also no need of `redundant cat` since file can be read from stdin redirection.